# MVC Application_BeginRequest localhost redirected you too many times

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to implement a "Maintenance Mode" into my application.  My thought is to "RedirectToRoute" when detected.  However, I am getting the following exception:

> "localhost redirected you too many times"

I've looked at various online solutions, but none work.  Any help is appreciated.

**GLOBAL ASAX:**

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var inMaintenanceMode = false;

    bool.TryParse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[Settings.Application.Modes.MaintenanceMode], out inMaintenanceMode);
    if (inMaintenanceMode)
    {
        Response.RedirectToRoute("Default", new { controller = "Maintenance", action = "Index" });
        Response.End();
        return;
    }
}
```

**CONTROLLER:**
It never gets here...

```
public class MaintenanceController : Controller
{
    // GET: Maintenance
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var viewModel = new MaintenanceIndexViewModel();

        // Forces a new Session_Start attempt
        Session.Abandon();

        return View(viewModel);
    } 
}
```

Comment: I think you need custom route constraint

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid the infinite redirect loop you could add an additional check in your `Application_BeginRequest` method whether the current route is the `Maintenance` controller and if so, skip the redirect as you have already redirected to it in the previous request.

Comment: How do I do that from "Application_BeginRequest"

Comment: You can start by looking at `Request.Url`. It will definitely give you hints about the `Maintenance` controller being present in it, that you should be looking for.

Comment: "HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values" is empty

Comment: I didn't say `HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Value`. I said `Request.Url` - that's not quite the same thing.

Comment: I know...I was trying something out.  Your suggestion works.  Thanks man

Comment: In fact `Application_BeginRequest` happens very early in the execution pipeline, much earlier than the specific MVC artifacts are populated.